# Angular JS adding an extra module causes project to not render any pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry if this is a noob question but I am brand new to Angular JS.

While programming my web app I wanted to add an extra page to my website. Currently I have a main module that contains smaller modules for each webpage:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

This works fine but when I try and add an extra module 'myApp.view3' none of the pages render. Here is what the modules look like:

view1

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])
// configuration
.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
            templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
            controller: 'View1Ctrl'
        });
}])//controller and factory not shown
```

view 3

```
angular.module('myApp.view3', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
            templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
            controller: 'View3Ctrl'
        });
}])

.controller('View3Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

}
]);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just realized I had forgot to include the JS script within the HTML file